Can we use has been raining as has stopped
I am not sure and I dare not to use that has been raining as the rain has stopped.
Now it is at noon and I want to express it was raining all morning.
The rain has stopped now.But I want to use "has been raining" as the rain has stopped.

It has been raining all the morning and I go out to the park. Due to the rain, the park is so fresh.

In this context can I use has been raining as it was raining all morning.
Now it is evening and the rain was falling all day time. Here also can I use has been raining all day time and it has stopped now.

It has been raining all day , so we walk to the park , as you know we can feel the air is so fresh and healthy.

In this context can I use has been raining all day as it was raining all day.
It is correct?

It can indicate that the rain has stopped, but that isn't the main point. The main point is that "there was rain" and it contrasts with "there was no rain". The rain might start again.  It means "Now it is wet", and not "now it is not raining". That is, it doesn't contrast with "it is raining now".
So, "It has been raining, so I'm going to the park now" seems strange. It seems like you would not go to the park when it is dry.
It is simpler to say "It has stopped raining."
Much of the rest of the tenses in your examples are wrong.  "I go to the park" means "always or generally".  "due to raining" and "after raining"  are not correct, and nor is "around the park is fresh".  You punctuation is wrong and confusing.  You have no commas after the introductory phrase "due to raining" and there is a comma splice in the second example.  You have inserted spaces at random around punctuation marks.

Yes , I need to keep learning , but I used simple way as much as I can to know the situation that the rain has stopped although I used it has been raining all day and all morning.I have read explanation with for and since which indicates still raining.Thats why I was eager to know as my question. Now I understand that indicates the rain has stopped.Thank you very much@James K

Sorry , it has stopped raining ,in which I understand the usage. Thank you @James K

To me, it has been raining all morning/day implies that it is still raining, unless you specify that it has stopped.
